# Insert date and time into MySQL with ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, datetime, coldfusion

I am totally lost here.

There is a field of type "datetime" in MySQL database. I want to populate it with a datetime generated by ColdFusion program. I found that CreateODBCDateTime has to be used to convert to propert format so that MySQL would accept it, so...

```
<cfset myDateTime = CreateODBCDateTime("07-04-2012 20:11:00")>
```

And somewhere later:

```
<cfquery name="qAddDate">
    INSERT INTO some_table
    (`date`)
    VALUES
    ('#myDateTime#')
</cfquery>
```

However, I get this error when try to send data to database:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2012-07-04 20:11:00'}')' at line 8

Line 8 is the line with date:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
(`date`)
VALUES
('{ts '2012-07-04 20:11:00'}')
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need quotes around date *objects*, only strings.  Removing the quotes should resolve your syntax error:

```
  INSERT INTO some_table (`date`)
  VALUES ( #myDateTime# )
```

Though you should get into the habit of using `cfqueryparam`

```
  INSERT INTO some_table (`date`)
  VALUES ( <cfqueryparam value="#myDateTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"> )
```

...  OR if it is a valid/parseable US date string, you could skip the createODBCDate and just use:

```
  INSERT INTO some_table (`date`)
  VALUES ( <cfqueryparam value="07-04-2012 20:11:00" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"> )
```

Comment: If you use `#createODBCDate(NOW())#`, it will only pass the date part, so as suggested, use `<cfqueryparam value=#createODBCDate(NOW())# cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" list="no"` to pass the time portion as well.

Comment: @user2297366 - Did you mean CreateODBCDateTime? Because using CreateODBCDate *removes* the time portion instead of passing it to the db, regardless of whether you use cf_sql_timestamp or not. Side note, if you need the current date and time, skip the createODBCDate/Time() and just use `now()`. It most cases the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

These look like "back ticks", which would cause a problem. Of course, I have not used MySQL, so I can't say for sure.

```
(`date`)
```

You should be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table(date)
VALUES ('{ts '2012-07-04 20:11:00'}')
```

Comment: Actually he probably needs them for mySQL because `Date` is usually a reserved word. (Back ticks are a valid escape character in mySQL) The syntax error is probably caused by the single quotes around the date object value.

Comment: @Leigh, thanks for clearing that up. I didn't notice the "MySQL" part of the question. I have never used MySQL.

Comment: I only use it occasionally. I remember I was so used to MS SQL's square brackets, the first time I saw the back ticks I thought "what the heck are those for?" It stuck in my mind ;)

Comment: Just came across this again. I wish people would leave comments when they down vote and not leave someone else holding the bag so to speak ;)

Comment: @Leigh, most people just aren't helpful. Luckily, most people on this site are. There's no bag to hold.

Comment: Yeah most of the people on SO are pretty decent. In general I just do not like down voting without comment. If something is wrong enough to warrant a down vote it also warrants a comment explaining why. Otherwise it defeats the purpose of having a collaborative site ie help improve and promote better answers. That is unlikely to happen if the recipient never knows what is wrong. {climbs down off soap box} ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet and output display (at bottom of post)

### show MySQL date field insertion and update using ColdFusion 10.

```
<CFOUTPUT>

  <CFSET mLST_UPDT = CreateODBCDate("07/04/2012")>

  Date for SQL Insert = #mLST_UPDT# <br>

<!---- INSERT code without use of cfqueryparam ---->
<CFQUERY NAME="TAB_INSERT" DATASOURCE="HELMSFARMS">
INSERT INTO DATE_TABLE (LST_UPDT) VALUES (#mLST_UPDT#)
</CFQUERY>

<!---- INSERT code using cfqueryparam ---->
<CFQUERY NAME="TAB_INSERT" DATASOURCE="HELMSFARMS">
INSERT INTO DATE_TABLE
(LST_UPDT)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#mLST_UPDT#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> ) 
</CFQUERY>

<!---- Getting and Displaying results of INSERT ---->
<CFQUERY NAME="GET_DATES1" DATASOURCE="HELMSFARMS">
SELECT LST_UPDT FROM DATE_TABLE  
</CFQUERY>

<CFLOOP QUERY="GET_DATES1">
#CURRENTROW#. #GET_DATES1.LST_UPDT# #dateformat(GET_DATES1.LST_UPDT,"mm/dd/yyyy")#
<br>
</CFLOOP>

<!---- Code that uses UPDATE on the records INSERTED above ---->
<cfset mNXT_UPDT = CreateODBCDate("08/05/2014")>
<br>
Date for SQL Update = #mNXT_UPDT# <br>

<!---- UPDATE code using cfqueryparam ---->
<CFQUERY NAME="GET_DATES2" DATASOURCE="HELMSFARMS">
UPDATE DATE_TABLE SET
LST_UPDT = <cfqueryparam value="#mNXT_UPDT#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_date" > 
</CFQUERY>

<CFQUERY NAME="GET_DATES2" DATASOURCE="HELMSFARMS">
SELECT LST_UPDT FROM DATE_TABLE  
</CFQUERY>

<CFLOOP QUERY="GET_DATES2">
#CURRENTROW#. #GET_DATES2.LST_UPDT# #dateformat(GET_DATES2.LST_UPDT,"mm/dd/yyyy")#<br>
</CFLOOP>

</CFOUTPUT>  

<!----- Results of running above code 
Used a MySQL table named DATE_TABLE with 
one Date Field named LST_UPDT
--------------------------------------
Date for SQL Insert = {d '2012-07-04'} 
1. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
2. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
3. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
4. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
5. {ts '2012-07-04 00:00:00'} 07/04/2012
6. {ts '2012-07-04 00:00:00'} 07/04/2012
Date for SQL Update = {d '2014-08-05'} 
1. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
2. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
3. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
4. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
5. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
6. {ts '2014-08-05 00:00:00'} 08/05/2014
---->
```