# Inserting datetime in MSSQL from Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to insert `NOW` into a MySQL table. Something like:

```
<cfset datatime = CREATEODBCDATETIME( Now() ) />

<cfquery name="qInsert" datasource="#dbanme#" >
   INSERT INTO TableName(....,date_created, date_modified)
   VALUES(...,'#datatime#', '#datatime#')
</cfquery>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> *Invalid JDBC timestamp escape*

Any help?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but is it a MSSQL or a MySQL table? You list one in the question and the other in the title. It kind of matters as you can use MySQL's `Now()` function or MSSQL's `getDate()` function to get the current date/time, no reason to have CF do it.

Comment: `createODBCDateTime` returns a datetime object. DateTime objects should *not* be quoted. [That is what is causing your syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057107/insert-date-and-time-into-mysql-with-coldfusion/10057405#10057405). That said, as others suggested you should really be using cfqueryparam on all variable parameter values.

Answer (score 13):

Let ColdFusion write out the data for you - using `cfqueryparam`. It's not absolutely essential here, but it's good practice to use it whenever you can. In addition to protecting you from SQL injection, it formats your variables appropriately so you don't have to worry about whether or not you need to insert the values as strings or integers or whatever.

```
<cfset datatime = CREATEODBCDATETIME( Now() ) />

<cfquery name="qInsert" datasource="#dbanme#" >
   INSERT INTO TableName(....,date_created, date_modified)
   VALUES(...,
        <cfqueryparam value="#datatime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#datatime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Did you mean `cf_sql_timestamp`? Because using `cf_sql_date` will remove any time portion and insert a date only.

Comment: oops, yeah - habit out of our own practices where we name things either `date_xx` or `datetime_xx` appropriately

Comment: Cool, I figured it was just a typo of sorts :) Thanks for updating it.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the date, without the time, use the following:

```
<cfquery name="qInsert" datasource="#dbanme#" >
   INSERT INTO TableName( ...., date_created, date_modified )
   VALUES ( ...
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#now()#">
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#now()#">
   )
</cfquery>
```

`cf_sql_date` will remove any time, and depending on your field type show either the date only or the date with `00:00:00` as the time value.

If you want a date with time:

```
<cfquery name="qInsert" datasource="#dbanme#" >
   INSERT INTO TableName ( ....,date_created, date_modified )
   VALUES ( ...
      , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
      , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
   )
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the built-in NOW function, just include it as part of the query:

```
<cfquery name="qInsert" datasource="#dbname#" >
   INSERT INTO TableName(....,date_created, date_modified)
   VALUES(...,NOW(), NOW())
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around the generated ColdFusion timestamps when inserting into SQL Server.

To elaborate, if you build up your timestamp as a string, using DateFormat and whatnot, you have to insert into using this format:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(DATE_COL) VALUES({ts '#dateInAStringFormat#'})
```

The ColdFusion ODBCx functions for dates do all this work for you, so it's just:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(DATE_COL) VALUES( #dateInAStringFormat# )
```