# SQL error in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

im trying to make a register for my CMS system. But whenever i try to create it, it gives me this error

> The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
>   Error Occurred While Processing Request
>   Error Executing Database Query.
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '0', '500000', '500000', ''2012-11-02 22:12:11'', '20', '1', 'hr-165-45.hd-20' at line 2

The SQL query is this:

```
<cfquery name="insertMale" datasource = "#DSN#">
INSERT INTO users (id, username, real_name, password, auth_ticket, rank, vip_points, credits, activity_points, activity_points_lastupdate, seasonal_currency, loyalty_points, look, gender, motto, mail, account_created, last_online, online, ip_last, ip_reg, home_room, newbie_status, is_muted, mutant_penalty, mutant_penalty_expire, trade_lock, trade_lock_expire, block_newfriends, hide_online, hide_inroom, vip, vip_expire, birth, talent_status, mysterybox_key_colour, last_name_change, client_volume, nux_passed, seckey, voted, vandeweek, home_txt, donateur, stemmen, waarschuwing)
VALUES('#countUsers.recordcount+1#', '#form.username#', 'Donny', '#password#', 'GRANDCMS-', 1', '0', '500000', '500000', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '20', '1', 'hr-165-45.hd-208-2.ch-250-64.lg-285-82.sh-290-64', 'M', 'Nieuw op GrandHotel!', '#form.mail#', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '0', '#CGI.REMOTE_ADDR#', '#CGI.REMOTE_ADDR#', '0', '0',  '0', '0', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '0', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '0', '0', '0', '0', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '24-12-1995', '0', '0', '#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#', '100', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'geenhometxt', '0', '0', '0');
</cfquery>
```

I counted the column's, it's the same so that isn't the problem. Anyone know's what i am doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad bad english. I'm from the netherlands!

Comment: `countUsers.recordcount+1` isn't very safe. You shouldn't insert untrustfull form-values. You should use cfqueryparams. I hope you don't have another query named `insertFemale`:)

Comment: Also, it seems like a lot of what you're inserting is flat values. MySQL could insert a lot of these default values on its own and your query doesn't need to be so massive and so hard to work on.

Comment: `countUsers.recordcount+1` is not user supplied. It is generated by the CF server. However, using it for an "ID" (which implies unique key) is a bad choice because it is not thread safe. If multiple threads executed that code at that same time they would all generate the same `id`. If you need an auto incrementing ID, do not re-inevent the wheel. That feature is already built into MySQL: [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 2):

Change `1'`, there is something missing!

Comment: Well, that fixed one problem. Now i got another one;S, I see that the script says that there is a } in the query. but there clearly isnt o-O

Comment: your dateadd() is creating a datetime which looks like `{ts '2010-06-01 00:00:00'}` and this is breaking your sql-statement. You should use `CFQUERYPARAM`s

Comment: @Donny That is an entirely separate question and should be asked as such. Apologies, that is how this site works, one topic per question. DateTime objects do not need 's around them. Unrelated, but important, you should be using `cfqueryparam` in all your queries. The nice part about CFQueryParam is that it does the quoting for you based on datatype.

Comment: @DonnySchr - As da_didi said, the cause of the error is wrapping your date *objects* in single quotes. [You do not need to use quotes on date *objects*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057107/insert-date-and-time-into-mysql-with-coldfusion/10057405#10057405). However, that query is vulnerable to sql injection. To protect your database, you should use [`cfqueryparam`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) on ALL variable query parameters.

Comment: *the cause of the error is wrapping your date objects in single quotes* To clarify, CF automatically escapes single quotes *within* a query variables, as a last line of defense against sql injection. Since the string representation of date objects contain single quotes, as @da_didi showed, CF will escape the quotes, resulting in the syntax error you are seeing. While removing the outer quotes would solve the error, the better solution is to use cfqueryparam. It not only does a better job protecting against sql injection - it also helps boost performance via bind variables.