# Processing Incoming Mail from Mailgun with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, mailgun

I've just started using Mailgun for 2-way emails within a web app I'm developing for in-house use.  I have a route set up to forward messages to a URL on my server - which is working fine.

However, the code at my end to process these messages is throwing errors.  Malign sends the data as a http post, which I can then reference with a form variable. Initially I was getting 'not defined' errors on some fields (those with hyphens in the field names), however that now appears to be resolved.  The code is now stumbling on the CFQUERY insert, with the error stating I have an error in the SQL syntax - but I can't see anything wrong with it!

This is the code I have for the page mailgun sends the post to;

```
<cfset thebody = form["body-plain"]> 
<cfset thesender = form["sender"]>
<cfset therecipient = form["sender"]>
<cfset thesubject = form["subject"]>

<cfquery name="addmail">
INSERT INTO mailmessages(from,sender,recipient,subject,body,msgdate)
VALUES('#thesender#','#thesender#','#therecipient#','#thesubject#','#thebody#',#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#)
</cfquery>
```

The error message states;

```
Error Executing Database Query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,sender,recipient,subject,body,msgdate) VALUES('lee@mydomain.com','l' at line 1
```

A cfdump of the form can be seen here (this is sent to be via cfmail in a cfcatch statement - the only way I'm able to see any errors);

[image: Cfdump]

Comment: I would start by using <cfqueryparam> on the values being inserted first, to rule out any text coming from Mailgun screwing it up.  If that still doesn't work maybe try/catch the SQL call and see what the error is...

Comment: And you might have to wrap the 'from' column to [from] (Not sure what the escape chars are for MySQL I'm afraid) as it's a reserved word and is probably being interpreted as such

Comment: Ah, a quick Google search suggests it's a double quote, so try changing the columns to ("from",sender,recipient,subject,body,msgdate)

Comment: Ah ha! It was the reserved word that was causing the problem! A quick change of the field names in the table (and associated query) and it works a treat.  You're correct on using the cfqueryparam too - it's something I generally do last (once everything works), though I have no idea why I do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **from** column name is a reserved word, so this is what mySQL is complaining about.

If you escape the column name, it should fix this.

Along with cfqueryparam your code should be something like:

```
<cfset thebody = form["body-plain"]> 
<cfset thesender = form["sender"]>
<cfset therecipient = form["sender"]>
<cfset thesubject = form["subject"]>

<cfquery name="addmail">
    INSERT INTO mailmessages (
        "from", 
        sender, 
        recipient, 
        subject, 
        body, 
        msgdate
    )
    VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam value="#thesender#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#thesender#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#therecipient#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#thesubject#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#thebody#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: *escape the column name* ... you can also rename the column and avoid the problem altogether :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, there is a syntax error in the insert query.
Seems like you are missing single quotes (`'`) around the date value you are passing. It should be written like this:

```
<cfquery name="addmail">
    INSERT INTO mailmessages(from,sender,recipient,subject,body,msgdate)
    VALUES('#thesender#','#thesender#','#therecipient#','#thesubject#','#thebody#','#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#')
</cfquery>
```

To get rid of such syntax errors and prevent SQL injection always use `cfqueryparams` like this:

```
<cfquery name="addmail">
    INSERT INTO mailmessages (from,sender,recipient,subject,body,msgdate)
    VALUES ( 
                <cfqueryparam  value="#thesender#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
                <cfqueryparam  value="#thesender#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
                <cfqueryparam  value="#therecipient#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
                <cfqueryparam  value="#thesubject#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
                <cfqueryparam  value="#thebody#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
                <cfqueryparam  value="#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP">
            )
</cfquery>
```

Instead of `CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP` you can also use `CF_SQL_DATE` as per your DB or data type you have specified for the column.

Comment: Quotes around the date cause an error, which is why I didn't have them.  You are correct about using cfqueryparams though, which is something I will do.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it fixes the problem, and uses best practices. If you aren't using `cfqueryparam` you're just asking for syntax errors due to bad data, and asking for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: @beloitdavisja - that wasn't the problem, the reserved word was the problem.

Comment: @beloitdavisja - Agreed about cfqueryparam, but technically first part of the answer is incorrect. Single quotes should *not* be used with createODBCDate/Time, as [it will cause a similar syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057107/insert-date-and-time-into-mysql-with-coldfusion/10057405#10057405).  That said, while it was not the problem in this case, using cfqueryparam is a good practice to avoid the potential for that kind of error (and protection) as you and Pankaj mentioned.

Comment: @Leigh Should I remove the first part of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can't select Jedihomer Townend's comment above as the answer, but he was correct to point out that my fieldnames contained reserved words, and that was causing the problem.  Changing those fixed it.

Comment: *can't select Jedihomer Townend's comment above as the answer* Use @ + username, to leave @JedihomerTownend a comment asking him to promote his comment to comment to an answer :)

Comment: @JedihomerTownend - yes, please do!